# Login and Register on same page with Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

So I'm creating an e-commerce website and working with Laravel 5.6 which I do not have as much experience as I would be comfortable with even though I took a Udemy course on it.

So if an unauthorized user `if(!Auth::check())` goes to the root directory `/` there is a login form along with a `Sign in` and `Sign up` button. The `Sign up` button is supposed to then change the form for signing in to sign up with additional fields like first and last name.

What is the most painless way to do this in Laravel 5.6? I was thinking maybe I could somehow utilize `@section` and `@yield` but I'm honestly not sure and I don't want to mess anything up.

Comment: The default auth page is a good example of that... it has a login and register link in the top nav area... What are you trying to achieve? Not sure I understand what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one page:

1. Create Login Form in this page
2. Create Register Form in this page too
3. Hide Register Form using CSS or whatever
4. Create event on Sign up button to hide Login Form and Show Register form using JS